# Are JWTs a secure option for user authentication?

Tags: security, jwt

I like the simplicity of JWTs and just used them when implementing an authentication mechanism for an web app where I have an Elixir/Phoenix backend that serves a RESTful JSON API and an Angular 2 frontend.

Today I stumbled about [this](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/) article (I'm in no way affiliated with this website) and it gave me some doubts about the use of JWT which I would like to discuss. Mainly:

- There is no real way of JWTs to be invalidated without shutting down
  the whole system. At least when they are stateless.
- That means you cannot revoke access, which could be very bad.
- LocalStorage - where JWTs are mostly stored on the front-end side - is not as secure as Session Storage.

> Local storage, unlike cookies, doesn’t send the contents of your data
>   store with every single request. The only way to retrieve data out of
>   local storage is by using JavaScript, which means any attacker
>   supplied JavaScript that passes the Content Security Policy can access
>   and exfiltrate it. Not only that, but JavaScript also doesn’t care or
>   track whether or not the data is sent over HTTPS. As far as JavaScript
>   is concerned, it’s just data and the browser will operate on it like
>   it would any other data.
>
> After all the trouble those engineers went through to make sure nobody
>   is going to make off with our cookie jar, here we are trying to ignore
>   all the fancy tricks they’ve given us. That seems a little backwards
>   to me.

So far I think his points are not valid - as long as one serves everything via https and protects against XSS and CORS attacks. I mean if malicious JS can be executed on the site this is really not a problem of JWT. And JS does not allow mixed content (http and https).

For invalidating all tokens: Just use something like a JWT generation-number variable, that could live in your environment variables and is encoded in every token. It is a simple integer. If you want to invalidate all tokens, increment it. Then you just need a mechanism to check if the generation number matches. This doesn't have to hit the DB and shouldn't be a performance issue. And it shouldn't be too difficult to roll this out over multiple instances with a solid deployment strategy.

For invalidating a single token: Use refresh tokens and a very short lifespan for a JWT (couple of minutes). If the TTL of the JWT is almost over, the user get's a new one via the refresh token. This means a DB hit every couple of minutes.

Or am I mistaken?

Comment: "this is really not a problem of JWT" --- it's not, but then you lost a token and you have no easy way to invalidate it.

Comment: "Use refresh tokens and a very short lifespan for a JWT " --- if you lost it someone can maliciously refresh it for infinite span of time. "This means a DB hit every couple of minutes." --- then you don't need JWT and can use normal sessions.

Comment: @zerkms First of all: How would you go about losing a token? It could be intercepted, if you don't use SSL. But that is true for Cookies as well and is just session hijacking. But let's say it happened: With the refresh-token strategy you can easily invalidate single tokens. And your second argument that if you hit the DB every couple of minutes you can as well use sessions: I disagree. There are more advantages of JWTs then just minimizing hits on the DB. And every couple of minutes is still magnitudes better than on every request.

Comment: "How would you go about losing a token?" --- XSS

Comment: Well, XSS is a completely different topic. If your site is open to XSS attacks it is not the fault of JWT and you have a big problem anyways.

Comment: It's not a fault of JWT - my comment was only about how cookies are better than *Storages.

Comment: Sorry, no, it wasn't. It was about what would happen if you loose a token. Not about how cookies are better.

Comment: I'm not sure how you manage to know what I meant better than me. "LocalStorage - where JWTs are mostly stored on the front-end side - is not as secure as Session Storage.". You wanted to discuss this item. I mentioned how cookies are better. "It was about what would happen if you loose a token" --- nope.

Answer (score 5):

> LocalStorage - where JWTs are mostly stored on the front-end side - is
>   not as secure as Session Storage.

You could always store your JWTs within [HttpOnly cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly), which will mitigate the risk of them being stolen by any XSS vulnerability.

Of course all the other usual best practices apply - secure flag, HSTS, etc.

> For invalidating all tokens: Just use something like a JWT
>   generation-number variable, that could live in your environment
>   variables and is encoded in every token

Yes, you could do that or even generate new secrets entirely.

> For invalidating a single token: Use refresh tokens and a very short lifespan for a JWT
>   (couple of minutes). If the TTL of the JWT is almost over, the user
>   get's a new one via the refresh token. This means a DB hit every
>   couple of minutes.

So I'm assuming this means using traditional server-side session state mechanisms for your refesh-tokens? This seems a valid approach. Ensure the session tokens are hashed server-side though with a secure algorithm (e.g. SHA-2 - no salt is required).

The only tricky part is clock synchronisation from client to server. If you're expiring them quickly, then any small clock differences may confuse the client and they won't request the refresh token in time. This is making things more complicated, and complexity is the main enemy of security.

If you're expiring tokens so quickly, it would probably make more sense to use traditional server-side session management mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The best Answer According to my experince is that store jwt key in that way that it should not be visible to anyone and suppose if that happen we have lots of method such as use time validation that the key will expire in minutes and also we can use a function to generate different jwt key all the time dynamically using random function its my opinion and experince
Thank you